# Laravel HasMany has no attach or associate method?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I store relationship in variable:

```
$relation = $model->{$relationConfig['relation']}();
```

then i make sure that its indeed HasMany relationship:

```
dd($relation);
```

And i see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3i3b.png). Then, i am using it like so:

```
$relation->associate($newModel);
```

And then this error happens:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::associate()
```

Whats wrong am i doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newModel = new Child([
  'column' => 'value',
])
$relation = Parent::create([
  'column' => 'value'
]);
$newModel->belongsToRelation()->associate($relation);
$newModel->save();
//or
$relation = Parent::find(1)->hasMany()->create([
  'column' => 'value'
]);
```

Comment: I know that i can use child's belongsTo relation, but i dont want to store reverse relationship name in config...

Comment: then use $relation->hasMany()->save($newModel);